# How to rerender or refresh or get js code to work properly for different resolutions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had seen that there is similar questions, but couldn't find proper answer for my problem.

Code:

```
function test() {

var scroll = parseInt($('.sidebar').css('height'));

if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 769px)').matches) {

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ( $(window).scrollTop() > scroll  ) {      
            $('.element').addClass('fixed');
        } else {
            $('.element').removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
} } 

window.onload = function() { test(); }
```

As you can see this code (adding and removing simple class when scrolling) should work for resolutions bigger than 769px (width) and it works - when test this on mobile device with resolution 1024x768 at 1024px width - works fine, BUT the problem is when you rotate the device - now the width is 768px, but "fixed" class is again added and breaks layout. You have to refresh the whole page so the code to work properly.

I can make the whole page to reload on resize but this is slow and irritating for users.

Tried to set function and on resize but it doesn't work.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    clearTimeout(window.resizedFinished);
    window.resizedFinished = setTimeout(function(){
        test();
    }, 10);
});
```

Tried to add "else" for the if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 769px)').matches) but it doesn't work too.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scroll-event is added onload, and not removed on the resize-event. So the event-function is still being triggered. How about:

```
 $(window).on('scroll resize', function() { // On both scroll and resize, call
    if (
        window.matchMedia('(min-width: 769px)').matches 
        && $(window).scrollTop() > scroll  
    ) {      
        $('.element').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        $('.element').removeClass('fixed');
    }
});
```